# Как происходит сравнение строк и чисел?

Tags: javascript, строки, сравнение, числа

Я не понимаю что происходит. При изменении знака результат 1 - `false`.

```js
console.log('Ava' < 65); //false
console.log('Ava' > 65); //false
```

Почему так происходит? Как в этом случае происходит сравнение?

Comment: 'Ava' является NaN (Not a Number), а NaN не больше и не меньше, чем 65.

Comment: Тут скорее другой вопрос уместен: а что ты ожидаешь при таком сравнении?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский я думал, что... сравнение строк же происходит по числовым индексам юникода, ну и 'A' имеет кодовую точку 65, дальше сравнение по 2-му символу... тут как я понимаю по-другому, "строчное" сравнение будет выполнено только если 2 операнда - строки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По [спецификации](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison): если оба операнда не являются строками, то идет приведение к числу.

В данном случае `'Ava'` при приведении к числу даст `NaN`, который в любых операциях сравнения даст `false`.